# Problems Implementing XPBD in to Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, physics-engine

I've been trying to implement a softbody simulation into Unity based on XPBD (Extended Position Based Dynamics).The tutorial that I have been following is from Matthias Muller from the Youtube channel Ten Minute Physics. You can find the code for the tutorial here: https://github.com/matthias-research/pages/blob/master/tenMinutePhysics/10-softBodies.html. And here is a link for the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uCaHXkS2cUg

I tried to convert certain things into a more "Unity" way of doing things. Such as the use of Vectors objects. But regardless of what I do the simulation would either explode or it would fail by not fighting to keep its shape against gravity. I ended up simplifying the simulation to just a single line of Distance constraints but it still does not work as expected.

Here is my code that just uses the distance constraints. This script is attached to an empty GameObject located at the world origin:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class RopeDynamics : MonoBehaviour
{
    public MeshFilter meshFilter;

    public bool showIndexes = true;
    public int indexLabelSize = 16;

    public int subSteps = 10;
    public float edgeCompliance = 100f;
    public float mass = 1f;


    public Vector3[] nodes;
    public int[] edgeNodeIds;

    [SerializeField]
    private float[] _restEdgeLengths;    
    [SerializeField]
    private float[] _inverseMasses;
    [SerializeField]
    private Vector3[] _velocities;
    [SerializeField]
    private Vector3[] _prevPositions;

    private Vector3 _gravity;
    private Vector3[] _gradients = new Vector3[4];

    public int NodeCount
    {
        get
        {
            return nodes.Length;
        }
    }

    public int EdgeCount
    {
        get
        {
            return edgeNodeIds.Length / 2;
        }
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        //Create the Rope Nodes/Vertices.
        nodes = new Vector3[]
        {
            new Vector3(0f,2f,0f),
            new Vector3(0f,1.75f,0f),
            new Vector3(0f,1.5f,0f),
            new Vector3(0f,1.25f,0f),
            new Vector3(0f,1f,0f),
            new Vector3(0f,0.75f,0f),
            new Vector3(0f,0.5f,0f)
        };

        edgeNodeIds = new int[]
        {
            0,1,
            1,2,
            2,3,
            3,4,
            4,5,
            5,6
        };

        var mesh = new Mesh();
        mesh.vertices = nodes;
        mesh.SetIndices(edgeNodeIds, MeshTopology.Lines, 0);
        mesh.RecalculateBounds();
        meshFilter.mesh = mesh;

        //Get Local Vector of Gravity.
        _gravity = transform.InverseTransformDirection(Physics.gravity);

        InitializeSimulation();
    }


    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //Get the Substep.
        var sdt = Time.fixedDeltaTime / subSteps;

        for (int i = 0; i < subSteps; i++)
        {

            PreSolve(sdt, _gravity);
            Solve(sdt);
            PostSolve(sdt);
        }
    }


    private void InitializeSimulation()
    {
        //Initialize the Arrays.
        _restEdgeLengths = new float[EdgeCount];
        //_restVolumes = new float[tetMesh.TetrahedronCount];
        _inverseMasses = new float[NodeCount];
        _velocities = new Vector3[NodeCount];
        _prevPositions = new Vector3[NodeCount];

        //Get all of the Rest Lengths for each Edge.
        for (int i = 0; i < EdgeCount; i++)
        {
            //_restEdgeLengths[i] = tetMesh.GetSqrEdgeLength(i);
            _restEdgeLengths[i] = GetMagEdgeLength(i);
        }

        var w = 1f / (mass / NodeCount);

        //Get all of the Inverse Masses.
        for (int i = 0; i < NodeCount; i++)
        {
            _inverseMasses[i] = w;            
        }

        _inverseMasses[0] = 0f;
    }

    private void PreSolve(float dTime, Vector3 gravity)
    {
        //For each node.
        for (int i = 0; i < NodeCount; i++)
        {
            //Skip if the Inverse Mass is Zero/Infinite.
            if (_inverseMasses[i] == 0f)
                continue;

            //Get selected Velocity and add the Gravity vector.
            _velocities[i] += gravity * dTime;

            //Cache Previous Position.
            _prevPositions[i] = nodes[i];

            //Add Velocity vector to the Nodes Position vector.
            nodes[i] += _velocities[i] * dTime;
        }

    }

    private void Solve(float dTime)
    {
        SolveEdges(dTime, edgeCompliance);        
    }

    private void PostSolve(float dTime)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < NodeCount; i++)
        {
            //Skip if the Inverse Mass is Zero/Infinite.
            if (_inverseMasses[i] == 0f)
                continue;

            //Update the selected Velocity.
            _velocities[i] = (nodes[i] - _prevPositions[i]) / dTime;
        }

        //Update the Mesh.
        UpdateMesh();
    }

    private void SolveEdges(float dTime, float compliance)
    {
        //Calculate the alpha for stiffness.
        var alpha = compliance / (dTime * dTime);

        //For each Edge.
        for (int i = 0; i < EdgeCount; i++)
        {
            //Get the Node Id's for the selected Edge.
            var ids = GetEdgeNodeIds(i);
            var eNodes = GetEdgeNodes(i);

            //Get the Inverse Masses for each Node.
            var w0 = _inverseMasses[ids[0]];
            var w1 = _inverseMasses[ids[1]];

            var w = w0 + w1;

            if (w == 0f)
                continue;

            //Get the current length of the edge.
            //var len = tetMesh.GetSqrEdgeLength(i);
            var len = GetMagEdgeLength(i);

            //Check if current length is Zero.
            if (len == 0f)
                continue;

            //Get the error between the current length and the rest length.
            var c = len - _restEdgeLengths[i];

            //Get the Vector difference between the two Nodes.
            var diff = eNodes[1] - eNodes[0];

            //Calculate the Gradient.
            _gradients[0] = diff / len;
            _gradients[1] = -_gradients[0];

            var gradMag0 = Vector3.Magnitude(_gradients[1]);
            var gradMag1 = Vector3.Magnitude(_gradients[0]);

            var gradSqr0 = gradMag0 * gradMag0;
            var gradSqr1 = gradMag1 * gradMag1;

            var s = -c / ((w0 * gradSqr0) + (w1 * gradSqr1) + alpha);

            var dX0 = (s * w0) * _gradients[1];
            var dX1 = (s * w1) * _gradients[0];
            

            nodes[ids[0]] += dX0;
            nodes[ids[1]] += dX1;
        }
    }

    private void UpdateMesh()
    {
        meshFilter.mesh.vertices = nodes;
    }

    public float GetMagEdgeLength(int index)
    {
        //Get the Nodes of the selected Edge.
        var node1 = nodes[edgeNodeIds[2 * index]];        
        var node2 = nodes[edgeNodeIds[2 * index + 1]];

        //Return the Squared Manitude of the 2 Points.
        return Vector3.Magnitude(node2 - node1);
    }

    public Vector3[] GetEdgeNodes(int index)
    {
        return new Vector3[2]
        {
            nodes[edgeNodeIds[2 * index]],
            nodes[edgeNodeIds[2 * index + 1]],
        };
    }

    public int[] GetEdgeNodeIds(int index)
    {
        return new int[2]
        {
            edgeNodeIds[2 * index],
            edgeNodeIds[2 * index + 1]
        };
    }

    //Used to draw spheres at the Nodes/Vertices.
    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.blue;
        GUI.contentColor = Color.blue;

        if (showIndexes)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < NodeCount; i++)
            {
                var point = transform.TransformPoint(meshFilter.sharedMesh.vertices[i]);

                Gizmos.DrawSphere(point, 0.008f);

                Handles.Label(point, i.ToString(), new GUIStyle(GUI.skin.label) { fontSize = indexLabelSize });
            }
        }

    }

}
```

I just can't seem to figure out what is wrong. It's probably something simple but I just can't see it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Haven't gone through it completely but are you certain that where you access gradients, you always want 0 and 1 indices, rather than ids[0] and ids[1]?

Comment: Hi Bart, thanks for the response. Yes, I believe so. The gradient array is just a buffer with a length of 4. This imitates the source material. However, since I haven't implemented the volume constraint I only use the first two indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So just in case anyone else is stuck I will post my solution here.

First I found the actually papers that outlined the definitions of [PBD](https://matthias-research.github.io/pages/publications/posBasedDyn.pdf) and [XPBD](https://matthias-research.github.io/pages/publications/XPBD.pdf/). Also I found the implementations found in the article ["Detailed Rigid Body Simulation with Extended Position Based Dynamics"](https://matthias-research.github.io/pages/publications/PBDBodies.pdf) to be most helpful.

In addition, there is a project from a user called Q-Minh on Github called ["position-based-dynamics"](https://github.com/Q-Minh/position-based-dynamics). They implement the principle of a XPD solver into a c++ program that made it much easier to get my code working.

If you use these scripts you will need a GameObject that has a MeshFilter and a MeshRenderer component.

```
using System;    
using UnityEngine;

public class RopeDynamics : MonoBehaviour
{
    public MeshFilter meshFilter;

    public int subSteps = 10;
    public int iterations = 3;

    public float edgeCompliance = 0.5f;
    public float mass = 1f;


    public Vector3[] nodes;
    public int[] edgeNodeIds;

    [SerializeField]
    private float[] _restEdgeLengths;    
    [SerializeField]
    private float[] _inverseMasses;
    [SerializeField]
    private Vector3[] _velocities;
    [SerializeField]
    private Vector3[] _prevPositions;

    private Vector3 _gravity;

    private float[] _lagrange;

    private bool _isInitialized = false;

    public int NodeCount
    {
        get
        {
            return nodes.Length;
        }
    }

    public int EdgeCount
    {
        get
        {
            return edgeNodeIds.Length / 2;
        }
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        //Create the Rope Nodes/Vertices.
        nodes = new Vector3[]
        {
            new Vector3(0f,2f,0f),
            new Vector3(0f,1.75f,0f),
            new Vector3(0f,1.5f,0f),
            new Vector3(0f,1.25f,0f),
            new Vector3(0f,1f,0f),
            new Vector3(0f,0.75f,0f),
            new Vector3(0f,0.5f,0f)
        };

        edgeNodeIds = new int[]
        {
            0,1,
            1,2,
            2,3,
            3,4,
            4,5,
            5,6
        };

        var mesh = new Mesh();
        mesh.vertices = nodes;
        mesh.SetIndices(edgeNodeIds, MeshTopology.Lines, 0);
        mesh.RecalculateBounds();
        meshFilter.mesh = mesh;

        //Get Local Vector of Gravity.
        _gravity = transform.InverseTransformDirection(Physics.gravity);

        InitializeSimulation();
    }


    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (!_isInitialized)
            return;

        //Get the Substep.
        var sdt = Time.fixedDeltaTime / subSteps;

        for (int i = 0; i < subSteps; i++)
        {

            PreSolve(sdt, _gravity);

            //Clear the Values of the Lagrange Multipliers.
            Array.Clear(_lagrange, 0, _lagrange.Length);
            for (int n = 0; n < iterations; n++)
            {
                Solve(sdt);
            }
        
            PostSolve(sdt);
        }
    }


    private void InitializeSimulation()
    {
        //Initialize the Arrays.
        _restEdgeLengths = new float[EdgeCount];        
        _inverseMasses = new float[NodeCount];
        _velocities = new Vector3[NodeCount];
        _prevPositions = new Vector3[NodeCount];
        _lagrange = new float[EdgeCount];
    

        //Get all of the Rest Lengths for each Edge.
        for (int i = 0; i < EdgeCount; i++)
        {
            //_restEdgeLengths[i] = tetMesh.GetSqrEdgeLength(i);
            _restEdgeLengths[i] = GetMagEdgeLength(i);
        }

        var w = 1f / (mass / NodeCount);

        //Get all of the Inverse Masses.
        for (int i = 0; i < NodeCount; i++)
        {
            _inverseMasses[i] = w;            
        }

        _inverseMasses[0] = 0f;
        //_inverseMasses[6] = 0f;

        _isInitialized = true;
    }


    private void PreSolve(float dTime, Vector3 gravity)
    {
        //For each node.
        for (int i = 0; i < NodeCount; i++)
        {
            var w = _inverseMasses[i];

            //Skip if the Inverse Mass is Zero/Infinite.
            if (w == 0f)
                continue;

            //Get selected Velocity and add the Gravity vector.
            _velocities[i] += (gravity * dTime) / w;

            //Cache Previous Position.
            _prevPositions[i] = nodes[i];

            //Add Velocity vector to the Nodes Position vector.
            nodes[i] += _velocities[i] * dTime;
        }

    }

    private void Solve(float dTime)
    {
        SolveEdges(dTime, edgeCompliance);                
    }

    private void PostSolve(float dTime)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < NodeCount; i++)
        {
            //Skip if the Inverse Mass is Zero/Infinite.
            if (_inverseMasses[i] == 0f)
                continue;

            //Update the selected Velocity.
            _velocities[i] = (nodes[i] - _prevPositions[i]) / dTime;
        }

        //Update the Mesh.
        UpdateMesh();
    }

    private void SolveEdges(float dTime, float compliance)
    {
        //Calculate the alpha for stiffness.
        var alpha = compliance / (dTime * dTime);

        //For each Edge.
        for (int i = 0; i < EdgeCount; i++)
        {
            //Get the Node Id's for the selected Edge.
            var nodeIds = GetEdgeNodeIds(i);            

            //Get the Inverse Masses for each Node.
            var w0 = _inverseMasses[nodeIds[0]];
            var w1 = _inverseMasses[nodeIds[1]];

            //Sum the Inverse Masses.
            var w = w0 + w1;

            //If they are Infinite, Skip.
            if (w == 0f)
                continue;

            //Get the selected Edge Nodes/Vertices.
            var eNodes = GetEdgeNodes(i);

            //Get the current length of the edge.
            var len = GetMagEdgeLength(i);

            //Check if current length is Zero.
            if (len == 0f)
                continue;

            //Get the Constraint Error between the Current Length and the Rest length.
            var c = len - _restEdgeLengths[i];

            //Get the Direction of the Edge.
            var n = Vector3.Normalize((eNodes[0] - eNodes[1]));                        

            //Calculate the Delta Lagrange Multiplier.
            var dLag = -(c + alpha * _lagrange[i]) / (w + alpha);

            //This version also worked and I liked its result better.
            //But it doesnt match the source documentation.
            //var dLagrange = -(c - alpha * _lagrange[i]) / (w + alpha);

            //Add to the delta Lagrange Multiplier to Lagrange Multiplier.
            _lagrange[i] += dLag;

            //Cacluate the Delta Positions for each point.
            var p0 = (dLag * n);
            var p1 = (dLag * -n);

            //Add Delta Positions to Update the Positions.
            nodes[nodeIds[0]] += p0 * w0;
            nodes[nodeIds[1]] += p1 * w1;            
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Applies the changes performed by the simulation to the mesh.
    /// </summary>
    private void UpdateMesh()
    {
        //Update the Mesh Object Vertices.
        meshFilter.mesh.vertices = nodes;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Calculates the length of a selected edge.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="index">Id of the selected edge.</param>
    /// <returns>The length of the selected edge. Also known as its magnitude.</returns>
    public float GetMagEdgeLength(int index)
    {
        //Get the Nodes of the selected Edge.
        var node1 = nodes[edgeNodeIds[2 * index]];        
        var node2 = nodes[edgeNodeIds[2 * index + 1]];

        //Return the Manitude of the 2 Points.
        return Vector3.Magnitude(node2 - node1);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the nodes/vertices of the selected edge.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="index">Id of the selected edge.</param>
    /// <returns>The nodes/vertices of the selected edge.</returns>
    public Vector3[] GetEdgeNodes(int index)
    {
        return new Vector3[2]
        {
            nodes[edgeNodeIds[2 * index]],
            nodes[edgeNodeIds[2 * index + 1]],
        };
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the Id's of the Nodes/Vertices of the selected edge.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="index">Id of the selected edge.</param>
    /// <returns>The Id's of the Nodes/Vertices of the selected edge</returns>
    public int[] GetEdgeNodeIds(int index)
    {
        return new int[2]
        {
            edgeNodeIds[2 * index],
            edgeNodeIds[2 * index + 1]
        };
    }
}
```

Script used to preview the mesh Vertices:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshFilter))]
public class MeshDebugger : MonoBehaviour
{
    public MeshFilter meshFilter;

    public bool showVertices = true;
    public float vertexSize = 0.01f;

    public bool showVertexIndexes = true;
    public int indexLabelSize = 16;

    /// <summary>
    /// If enabled by the Unity Inspector. It draw somehelp debug UI in the Scene view.
    /// </summary>
    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        if (showVertices) 
        {            
            if (meshFilter != null && meshFilter.sharedMesh != null)
            {
                Gizmos.color = Color.blue;
                GUI.contentColor = Color.blue;

                for (int i = 0; i < meshFilter.sharedMesh.vertexCount; i++)
                {
                    //Covert Vertex position from Local to World Space.
                    var point = transform.TransformPoint(meshFilter.sharedMesh.vertices[i]);

                    Gizmos.DrawSphere(point, vertexSize);

                    //Draw Vertex Index?
                    if (showVertexIndexes)
                        Handles.Label(point, i.ToString(), new GUIStyle(GUI.skin.label) { fontSize = indexLabelSize });
                }
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

I am still working on the Volume Constraint. And then I will need to optimize the simulation for performance. But at least it works.

Anyways I hope this helps get anyone who needs it started.